# Private encryption and public decryption key pair

Tags: rsa

Is it possible to have the public component of a key pair being capable only of decryption?

Comment: Sure? If you encrypt with the private key? That's kind of how the whole thing works. Are you asking something else?

Comment: I thought the public key usually encrypts only and the private key decrypts and encrypts

Comment: Here's the question, though. Is it really protected if you have the key to unlock it as a public key?

Comment: The question is what is protected, if I just want to prove my identity by showing that I have the ability to encrypt arbitrary messages, shouldn't that be fine?

Comment: You just described the "signing" process.